# How to display date picker dialog box extends from linear layout view in android

Tags: android, date

I am making custom view extend from linear layout. but here i want to display date picker when click getdate button. how to do this?

```
 public class XmlTest extends LinearLayout implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnDateSetListener{


    Date = Calendar.getInstance();
                            btndate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    datePickerInput=v.getId();
                                    for (int d = 0; d < mlistDateTimeButton.size(); d++){
                                        if (listDateTimeButton.get(d).getId() == v.getId()){

                                             showDateDialog(etLocationTest, Date);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

}

protected void showDateDialog(EditText etLocationTest2, Calendar date2) {
        Log.i("", "Date showDateDialog ");
        activeDateDisplay = etLocationTest2;
        activeDate = date2;
            ((Activity) getContext()).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


    }
```

but could not display date picker dialog box. How to do this.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? getting any errors?

Comment: could not display datepicker dialog box, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreateView.
btndate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),datePickerListener,
                    year, mon,day);
            dialog.show();
      }
});
```

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        //Do whatever you want with selectedDay,selectedMonth and selectedYear
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps u too

I have added all the code to implements this in below

Save it in your class extending linearlayout

create a constructor getting context from where this class is initialsed. Code used and it works fine for me.

```
class XmlTest extends linearlayout{
DatePopListener mDatePopListener;
EditText edittext;
TextBox label;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
public  XmlTest(Context context,String labelText){
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
label.setText(labelText);
this.addView(label);
this.addView(txtBox);
txtBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      datePickerDialog.show();

    }
});
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        txtBox.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
    }

},newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


}
//Now you can do your task here whatever as the date will be available in txtBox
//Enter your code as your requirements
}
```